# How to make javascript write to itself, and then when that code is ran again say it's already been run and add to a counter

Tags: javascript

I'm somewhat new to javascript, but I had an idea, code where the user inputs code, and the machine remembers and it and assigns it to a random variable name, and spits out the things that happen, and the name of the variable so it can be called again.

Lets say I enter this:

```
var input1 = prompt("Hi how are you");
if(input1 = "good"){
alert("That's great!");
}else if(input1 = "bad"){
alert("I hope it perks up!");
}else{
alert("Input not recognized");
}
```

When he/she enters it it then assigns it to a variable first, so any code inside itself can't modify itself before that, so any code that modifies itself doing it won't have to worry, then it runs it. After it runs it displays the variable number so they can call it later.

One thing for the variable I might have to have it check to see if it already exists as a variable name, and if it does it recalculates a variable name.

So basically code that saves it to itself in a variable causing itself to grow.

Comment: You can run code in a variable with `eval()`.

Comment: Use an `if` statement in your code that tests the value of a persistent variable that you set each time your code is executed.  If you want that variable to persist from one web page to the next, then store and retrieve the variable contents in LocalStorage in the browser.  It is rare that the best solution is to actually modify code.  Instead you modify variables and you test those variables with a common piece of code and decide which behavior to carry out based on the contents of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-modifying code is generally not a good idea.

In this case, if all you want to do is remember something in a variable, one option is to use web storage, specifically local storage.

To get the value (with a default if none has ever been stored):

```
var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("value") || "0");
```

To save the value for next time:

```
localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(value));
```

`localStorage` is the browser-supplied object that manages local storage.

I'm using JSON because web storage only ever stores strings, so my general pattern is to store JSON text. In this specific case, for just a number, it's a bit overkill and you could just use `parseInt` or the unary `+` coercion trick:

```
// Loading
var value = +localStorage.getItem("value") || 0;

// Saving (will implicitly be coerced to a string)
localStorage.setItem("value", value);
```

I'm also using the curiously-powerful `||` operator (more about that [on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html))*.

More in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

[**Live Example** on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn09rqeh/) (Stack Snippets don't allow using web storage):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var value = +localStorage.getItem("value") || 0;
    ++value;
    alert("That was click #" + value + " on this browser.");
    localStorage.setItem("value", value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I should learn some more before I try this. Have a good day!